# jQuery show loader while page get reloading

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have created functionality using jQuery, so when user click on button it will make clear filter on that page and reload page.

While clearing filter loader is showing on page, but when reload page line come then that loader is getting hide and page is reloading.

What I want is loader must displayed when page getting reload.

Below is some code.

```
var finalURLStrings = urlFinal.replace("isInboxstring=True", "isInboxstring=False");
var finalURLString = finalURLStrings.replace("isInbox=True", "isInbox=False");
$("#loading").show();
window.location.href = finalURLString; // while executing this line I still want to show loader which get hide here.
```

Comment: You can't display anything as the page is being reloaded. This is because when a page request is made the current DOM is unloaded from memory. If you want to keep a loading indicator visible on the screen while an action is occurring you'll need to re-build your site to use a single page architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The `window.location` object can be used to get the current page address (URL) and to redirect the browser to a new page and New page always reload and loading any spinner not show in new page.

so use this code below code:

```
$("#loading").show();
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#loading").hide();
});
```